# Algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A function $f:R \to R$ satisfies $f(5−x)=f(5+x)$. If $f(x)=0$ has $5$ distinct real roots, what is the sum of all of the distinct real roots?

I found the above question on a site (brilliant.org) . Please help me.

I am unable to know from where to start.

Comment: $5+t$ is a root iff $5-t$ is a root.

Comment: Hint: since it has $5$ real roots, one of its roots $\lambda$ must satisfy $5 - \lambda = 5 + \lambda.$

Comment: What has this got to do with number theory? Is this an ongoing competition there?

Comment: So $5-x = 0$ $\implies x = 5$ . So I have : 5 + x = 10 . So the sum of the distinct real roots will be 10+5=  15?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes , but I don't care about that as I have already done it wrong. .. I dont' cheat others.

Comment: Ok. Followin Ju'x' hint you should get two pairs of roots with that symmetry, and one singleton root symmetric with itself :-)

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the condition is the same as $f(y) = f(10 -y)$ for all $y$.

So if $y_{0}$ is a root, so is $10 - y_{0}$.

Now if $y_{0} = 10 - y_{0}$, it follows $y_{0} = 5$. Since the root are distinct, only one root $y_{0}$ can equal $10 -y_{0}$, and the other four must go in pairs $y_{1} \ne 10 - y_{1}$, $y_{2} \ne 10 - y_{2}$.

Hence the sum is
$$
5 + 10 + 10 = 25.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\phi(x) = f(x+5)$. Then $\phi$ is even. Hence if $\phi(x_0) = 0$, then $\phi(-x_0) =0$. Since we are given that there are a finite number of roots, we have $\sum_{x \in \phi^{-1} \{0\}} x = 0$.

Finally, since $f^{-1} \{0 \} = \phi^{-1} \{0\} + \{5\}$, and we know that $|f^{-1} \{0 \}| =|\phi^{-1} \{0 \}| =  5$, we see that $\sum_{x \in f^{-1} \{0\}} x = \sum_{x \in \phi^{-1} \{0\}} x + 5 |\phi^{-1} \{0\}| = 0 + 5\cdot 5 = 25$.